# Cannot insert data with key in Grakn

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I am ingesting data into Grakn and getting this error

> There is more than one thing of type [person] that owns the key [949] of type [person-id].

This is my query:

```
insert $a isa customer, has customer-id "94929", has person-id "949";
```

This is my schema:

```
person sub entity, 
key person-id;

customer sub person, 
key customer-id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that there is an entity of type `person`, or a subtype of type `person`, that already has the id `"949"` in the database. If you run the following query, you should find 1 result.

```
match $x isa person, has person-id "949"; get;
```